# UITableView reload woes and Notifications

Tags: ios, uitableview, reload

I currently have a UITableView in my VC which gets loaded when the VC appears. This VC has subscribed to a notification in the notification center, the action method in the VC for this notification is to do a tableView reload.

There is another object which fetches data at regular intervals and once it is done fetching it posts a notification that the data has changed. I have noticed sometimes that this notification does not reach the VC and the tableview does not get loaded.. what am I missing?

Comment: There's not enough information here to diagnose your problem.  Show the code that subscribes to, sends, and receives the notifications.

Comment: Does the object that's fetching the data, fetch this data on a background thread? You might want to check and make sure that the notification it posts is on the main thread, as per apple's documentation:https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Articles/Threading.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001289-CEGJFDFG

Comment: The code fetching the data is using a NSURLConnection and it is started using [NSURLConnection start]. This causes the delegate methods :
– connectionDidFinishLoading:

Once I get the connectionDidFinishLoading I post the notification 

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DataUpdated"]

In the VC I have subscribed via : 

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(dataUpdated:) name:@"DataUpdated" object:nil];

and the mehtod : 

-(void)dataUpdated:sender
{
    [_tableView reloadData];
}